# How can I stop firefox (and possibly other browsers?) from stealing tab focus

Tags: windows-7, firefox

I've got a website that I use for school, and it has a javascript function on it that pops up a window on the site after a certain period of inactivity to warn you that you'll be logged out. When this triggers and the tab is open in the background, it automatically switches to that tab even when I'm actively doing something on another tab.

Can I set it so that it just does its thing without having to forcefully yank me back to that window?

Using Firefox 16 on Windows 7. It also does it on my Windows 8 laptop.

Comment: Can you check Tools->Options->Content->Click Advanced next to Enable Javascript. Is "Raise or lower windows" unchecked? If not uncheck it.

Comment: Also do you know if the new tab contains any flash (it could be hidden flash).

Comment: @amit_g "Raise Windows" was not checked... but as for the Flash question, I don't know. Adblock Lite doesn't show any swf blockable items

Answer (score 1):

This behavior existed for over 10 years in Firefox but [was fixed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=332195) in Firefox 44. The problem occurred whenever a Javascript `alert()` was fired on another tab. The `alert()` on the other tab would automatically steal the focus from the current tab.